# Mix (elixir) no such file or directory

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am trying to install elixir in ubuntu... I had followed [this instructions](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#installing-erlang).

Everthing seems fine, but when I try to execute the mix comand, system asnwered me this:

```
bash: /usr/bin/mix: No such file or directory
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Is that the exact error message? Can you paste the exact one if it's not?

Comment: Hi @Dogbert It says bash, not bahs... and the output is in spanish... But yes It is exactly the error message.

Comment: It says "/user/bin_mix"?

Comment: Ouch!! Sorry, sorry, sorry... I am editting

Comment: Does it say `/user` or `/usr` ?  `/usr` would be the standard place for it to be--`/user` would not be.  What happens if you type `/usr/bin/mix`?

Comment: sorry!! I was too tired... :( now it is correctly, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to `cd` into directory where `mix.exs` file is available ( `mix` isn't a global command that works everywhere)

Comment: OMG!!! I was toooooo tired!!! Thanks @OleksandrAvoyants that is the solution!!!

Comment: ok )) I will add an answer than to make it clear.

Comment: I don't see how being in a directory without `mix.exs` can cause "/usr/bin/mix: No such file or directory". You can run `mix` from any directory after installing Elixir. If you run it from a directory without `mix.exs`, you'll just get an error like "** (Mix) Could not find a Mix.Project, please ensure a mix.exs file is available".

Comment: Yes you are right, yesterday I thought that this is kind of error when people do rails new demo && rails server instead of rails new demo && cd demo && rails server. But now when I read this, seems that it doesn't have sense :)

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into the same problem. The guide you linked installs mix to */usr/local/bin/mix* instead of */usr/local/mix*. I created a symlink */usr/bin/mix* but expanding *$PATH* is probably a better way to fix this.

```
~$ mix
-bash: /usr/bin/mix: No such file or directory
~$ which mix
/usr/local/bin/mix
~$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/mix /usr/bin/mix
~$ mix
** (Mix) Could not find a Mix.Project, please ensure a mix.exs file is available
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case i have installed elixir using sudo so when you try to call it without sudo you'll get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into this. In my case it stemmed from having `CDPATH` set.

Unsetting it for the session with `unset CDPATH` and retrying did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I reinstalled Erlang via `sudo apt-get install erlang-base` and during installation, Elixir got removed altogether.

Fixed that by running `sudo apt-get install elixir`.

All repositories were preset for me already.